# How to select conversations where only two participants involved?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if participant A and participant B ever had any conversation between them **privately**. If they two involved in **group** chat, **I don't want** that conversation.

So how do I structure my query where it will check if `count(participant_id) == 2`?

I tried this but it gives error:

```
select conversation_id from chat where participant_id == A AND participant_id == B AND COUNT(participant_id) == 2
```

table structure
[image]

Comment: Try - SELECT count(*) c, `conversation_id` FROM `chat` GROUP BY `participant_id` HAVING c=2

Comment: @RohanKhude, it doesnt return anything

Comment: show your table structure

Comment: update your question add  the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: where is `participant_id `

Comment: @HappyCoding, participant_id is user_id above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
      conversation_id
FROM chat
GROUP BY
      conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT participant_id) = 2
AND MAX(participant_id) IN (A,B)
AND MIN(participant_id) IN (A,B)
```

The HAVING clause is required when trying to evaluate values that are calculated by aggregate functions such as count. You need to count just the unique ID's involved in the conversation too.

By the way, if this query returns nothing that may mean you don't have any conversations that meet the profile.

Comment: I tried your query, but it returns group chat that contains these two users as well. I want only private chat..pls refer my table above

Comment: what table? where is it?

Comment: altered query, please try it with the MIN and MAX calculations instead of a where clause.

Comment: Note that, while great, this solution relies works for the special case described (only 2 participants), so isn't scalabale.